# Asking about return type, list and set data structure in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a function compute a list to boolean matrix where `num_of_name: 'a list -> 'a -> int` : return a position of element in a list.

1) I would like `mat_of_dep_rel : 'a list -> bool array array.`

My problem is that from the first `List.iter` it should take a list `l` and not an empty list `[]`. But if I return `l` instead of `[]`, it will give me a type: `('a * 'a list) list -> boolean array array.` Which is not what I want.

I would like to know how can I return `mat_of_dep_rel: 'a list -> bool array array?`

```
let mat_of_dep_rel l =
  let n = List.length l in
  let m = Array.make_matrix n n false in
  List.iter (fun (s, ss) ->
    let i = num_of_name ss s in
    List.iter (fun t ->
      m.(i).( num_of_name ss t) <- true) ss) [];
  m;;
```

2) I have another functions compute equivalence classes, to compute an equivalence class : check an element i if it has a path `i -> j` and `j -> i` or itself. I would like it return for me a type `int list list`. In this code I force the return type `'list list` by put `j` in `[j].` My question is:

Is it correct if I force like that? If not how can I return the type I want `int list list.`

```
let eq_class m i =
     let mi = m.(i) in
     let aux = 
       List.fold_right (fun j l ->
     if j = i || mi.(j) && m.(j).(i) then
       [j] :: l else l) in
     aux [] [];;
```

Another function eq_classes compute a set of equivalence classes by collect all the equivalence class. I would like to use a list data structure more than using a set. But for the moment, I am not really understand about the code saying here.

Could you please explain for me? If I want to use a list data structure, how can I use it? What is a different between a list and a set data structure in OCaml? Advance/Disadvance of its?

```
let eq_classes m =
  IntSet.fold (fun i l -> IntMap.add i (eq_class m i) l)
    IntSet.empty IntMap.empty;;
```

3) My last question is that. After having all the equivalence classes I would like to sort them. I have another functions

```
let cmp m i j = if eq_class m i = eq_class m j then 0
  else if m.(i).(j) then -1 else 1;;

let eq_classes_sort m l = List.sort (cmp m) l;;
```

for the last function I want it return for me b`ool array array -> int list list` not `bool array array -> int list -> int list`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You should trust Ocaml type system. The `Set` and `List` modules are obviously different. sets are immutable, with a dichotomical O(log n) membership test. lists are also immutable, but membership test is linear O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite many things wrong or obscure about your questions, but I'll try to answer as well as possible.

#### Question 1

You're apparently trying to transform the representation of a dependency graph from a list to a matrix. It does not make any kind of sense to have a dependency graph represented as `'a list` (in fact, there is no *interesting* way to build a boolean matrix from an arbitrary list anyway) so you probably intended to use an `(int * int) list` of pairs, each pair `(i,j)` being a dependency `i -> j`.

If you instead have a `('a * 'a) list` of arbitrary pairs, you can easily number the elements using your `num_of_name` function to turn it into the aforementioned `(int * int) list`.

Once you have this, you can easily construct a matrix :

```
let matrix_of_dependencies dependencies =
  let n = List.fold_left (fun (i,j) acc -> max i (max j acc)) 0 dependencies in  
  let matrix = Array.make_matrix (n+1) (n+1) false in
  List.iter (fun (i,j) -> matrix.(i).(j) <- true) dependencies ;
  matrix

val matrix_of_dependencies : (int * int) list -> bool array array
```

You can also compute the parameter `n` outside the function and pass it in.

#### Question 2

An *equivalence class* is a set of elements that are all equivalent. A good representation for a set, in OCaml, would be a list (module `List`) or a set (module `Set`). A list-of-lists is not a valid representation for a set, so you have no reason to use one.

Your algorithm is obscure, since you're apparently performing a fold on an empty list, which will just return the initial value (an empty list). I assume that you intended to instead iterate over all entries in the matrix column.

```
let equivalence_class matrix element = 
  let column = matrix.(element) and set = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun element' dependency -> 
    if dependency then set := element' :: !set
  end column ;
  !set

val equivalence_class : bool array array -> int list
```

I only check for `i -> j` because, if your dependencies are indeed an equivalence relationship (reflexive, transitive, symmetrical), then `i -> j` *implies* `j -> i`. If your dependencies are *not* an equivalence relationship, then you are in fact looking for cycles in a graph representation of a relationship, which is an entirely different algorithm from what you suggested, unless you compute the *transitive closure* of your dependency graph first.

Sets and lists are both well-documented standard modules, and their documentation is freely available online. Ask questions on StackOverflow if you have *specific* issues with them.

You asked us to explain the piece of code you provide for `eq_classes`. The explanation is that it folds on an empty set, so it returns its initial value - an empty map. It is, as such, completely pointless. A more appropriate implementation would be:

```
let equivalence_classes matrix = 
  let classes = ref [] in 
  Array.iteri begin fun element _ ->
    if not (List.exists (List.mem element) !classes) then
      classes := equivalence_class matrix element :: !classes 
  end matrix ;
  !classes

val equivalence_classes : bool array array -> int list list
```

This returns all the equivalence classes as a list-of-lists (each equivalence class being an individual list).

#### Question 3

The type system is pointing out that you have defined a comparison function that works on `int`, so you can only use it to sort an `int list`. If you intend to sort an `int list list` (a list of equivalence classes), then you need to define a comparison function for `int list` elements.

Assuming that (as mentioned above) your dependency graph is *transitively closed*, all you have to do is use your existing comparison algorithm and apply it to arbitrary representants of each class:

```
let compare_classes matrix c c` = 
  match c, c` with 
    | h :: _, h' :: _ -> if matrix.(h).(h') then 1 else -1
    | _ -> 0 

let sort_equivalence_classes matrix = List.sort (compare_classes matrix)
```

This code assumes that 1. each equivalence class only appears once and 1. each equivalence class contains at least one element. Both assumptions are reasonable when working with equivalence classes, and it is a simple process to eliminate duplicates and empty classes beforehand.