# Asking about return type, list and set data structure in OCaml (Cont.)

Tags: list, ocaml

Thank you for a very fruitful answer I got from my previous question [Asking about return type, list and set data structure in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398072/asking-about-return-type-list-and-set-data-structure-in-ocaml). I have another question related to this topic but I think it is good to ask in a new question.

Here is a function (`order_xsds`) I used to compute and sort all equivalence classes. Because I want to used this function to sort my data so I transfer it to my data type (My data is an xsd type).

`val flatten : Xsd.xsd list -> Xsd.xsd list`

```
val transClosure : 'a array array -> 'a array array
let name_of_num (l: 'a list) (i: int) : 'a = List.nth l i;;
let order_xsds xsds =
    let flatten_xsds = flatten xsds in
    let xsds_matrix = matrix_of_dependencies flatten_xsds in
    let tc = transClosure xsds_matrix in
    let eq_classes_order = sort_eq_classes tc (eq_classes tc) in
    let xsds_of_ints = List.map (List.map (name_of_num flatten_xsds)) in
    let xsds_order = xsds_of_ints eq_classes_order in
    xsds_order;;
```

I am trying to write a function that print the output of sorted list.

```
val genr_type : Buffer.t -> Xsd.xsd -> unit
let rec genr_and_types b = function
  | [] -> ()
  | xsd :: xsds ->
    bprintf b "\n\nand %a%a" genr_type xsd genr_and_types 
     (List.flatten (order_xsds xsds));;

let genr_types b = function
    | [] -> assert false (* there is at least one builtin type *)
    | xsd :: xsds ->
      bprintf b "type %a%a" genr_type xsd genr_and_types 
    (List.flatten (order_xsds xsds))
```

I called `List.flatten` just because to fixed the type checked of OCaml, but I lose my information about the sorted of equivalence classes which give me a wrong answer.

I tried another function taking an xsds list of lists by using List.iter nested.

```
let rec genr_types b xsds= List.iter (fun xsd -> 
  List.iter (fun xsds -> bprintf b "\n\nand %a%a" genr_type xsd 
    genr_types (order_xsds xsds)) xsds)(List.flatten xsds);;
```

When I run my program cannot generated the result, it looks like it doesn't terminate.

I am trying to figure out how to print the result from the function "order_xsds" (val : Xsd.xsd list -> Xsd.xsd list list).

But I still stuck. I need your help to explain me how to go thought this problem.

Thank you for your help,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you are using `order_xsds` deep inside your print function.

If I guess correctly (but I might be wrong as I don't understand which problem you are trying to solve), you need to first generate the data you want to print, then try to print it. For instance, your print function can be something like:

```
let rec genr_types b (xsds_partition : Xsd.xsd list list) =
  List.iter (function
    | []   -> ()
    | h::t ->
      bprintf "type %a" genr_type h;
      List.iter (fun xsd -> bprintf b "\n\nand %a" genr_type xsd) t
  ) xsds_partition
```

Than you can call later:

```
let print_partitions b xsds = genr_types b (order_xsds xsds)
```